# What does the make target 'nonint_oldconfig' mean in the linux kernel Makefile?

Tags: linux, makefile, linux-kernel, kernel

Recent versions of the kernel don't seem to support this target. I'm playing around with a 2.6.32 kernel and one of the targets is `nonint_oldconfig`. I'm not sure what this target actually does.

Comment: Looks like a patch was added by Redhat to help with rpmbuilds of the kernel.  You will see an error stating that the nonint_oldconfig target failed when there is a CONFIG_* error in a .config file in the kernel tree for Redhat-derived distros.